# Aion Faucet for Test Coins

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, aion

I'm working on a simple dApp in AION and I need to have some aion coins to test with. Is there a faucet like the Ethereum Rinkby faucet?

Comment: The docs reference the [mastery faucet](https://docs.aion.network/docs/get-test-coins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow Peter! As DavOS pointed out, there's a faucet for the Mastery test network available. Here are the basic steps taken from the [Aion documentation](https://docs.aion.network/docs/get-test-coins).

1. Sign up or login to [Gitter](https://gitter.im).
2. Search for `mastery_faucet` and join the [Aion Mastery Faucet channel](https://gitter.im/aionnetwork/mastery_faucet).
3. Paste your public address into the channel.
4. A few seconds later the faucet-bot will reply saying your request has been processed.
5. You should now have 1 AION in the address you supplied.

Keep in mind that you can only ask for 1 AION per day from the `master_faucet` bot. There are a few kinks in this process at the moment. There is a faucet website planned to come out later this year apparently.

## Edit

This answer is now out of date. [Tipeveryday's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53655333/2878626) is correct and should be marked as the correct answer by OP.

Answer (score 3):

BlockxLabs provide a free faucet for [Ethereum](https://faucets.blockxlabs.com/ethereum), [Aion](https://faucets.blockxlabs.com/aion), and [Tron](https://faucets.blockxlabs.com/tron). For **Aion**:

1. Choose the **Mastery** Testnet
2. Provide an Aion Address
3. Press **Pour**

[image: Image of Faucet]